# textStyleRules not overriding IOS /TVOS accessibility settings

Tags: ios, avplayer, tvos, avplayeritem

I am using a custom player for HLS streaming with webvtt subtitles and want my subtitles should always display white color with a black outline border with a clear background with a specific font.
I used the below code to in AVPlayer to apply style on captions/subtitles

AVTe

```
xtStyleRule *rule1 = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc] initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
  (id)kCMTextMarkupAttributeCharacterBackgroundColorARGB : [self getARBB:[UIColor blackColor]]}];
   
  AVTextStyleRule *rule2 = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc] initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
  (id)kCMTextMarkupAttributeForegroundColorARGB : [self getARBB:[UIColor whiteColor]]}];
   
  AVTextStyleRule *rule3 = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc] initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
  (id)kCMTextMarkupAttributeBackgroundColorARGB : [self getARBB:[UIColor clearColor]]}];
   
  AVTextStyleRule *rule4 = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc] initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
   (id)kCMTextMarkupAttributeGenericFontFamilyName : (NSString*)kCMTextMarkupGenericFontNameSansSerif}];
   
  AVTextStyleRule *rule5 = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc] initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
      (id)kCMTextMarkupAttributeBaseFontSizePercentageRelativeToVideoHeight : @(10),
      (id)kCMTextMarkupAttributeCharacterEdgeStyle : (NSString*)kCMTextMarkupCharacterEdgeStyleUniform}];
   
  item.textStyleRules = @[rule1,rule2,rule3,rule4,rule5];
}
```

Even after applying style on captions it still displays options selected by the user in accessibility settings.
Could you please help me understand how I can always display movie subtitles in this format by ignoring what is selected in accessibility settings of device?